# Changing the duration of a Kafka Stream SessionWindows iteratively

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, windowing

Suppose I have a Kafka Stream with a SessioWindowing such as:

```
windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(inactivity_time).until(aWeek))
```

Would it be possible to change the *inactivity time gap* of the window iteratively depending on the arrival of the following records?

Such as if I have initially defined my `inactivity_time=360000` with the first record, would it be possible to modify this value if a second record of the same key doesn't arrive after `inactivity_time/2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with built-in functionality, unfortunately.

Doing so would require you to implement this custom functionality yourself, e.g. with the Processor API of Kafka Streams (the resulting Processors/Transformers you could then plug into the DSL of Kafka Streams).